# bluetoothd repeatedly pops up on nettop

Tags: bluetooth

I have disabled `bluetooth`, however `bluetoothd` repeatedly pops up in `nettop`. Any idea how to remove it and stop it from popping up every now and then?

Comment: What problem does this present to your use of the Mac?

Comment: Thats not the point, I am just asking if the above is possible?